# QL: Find Top 2 and reverse order

Tags: sql

I am having the IMDB database; I am looking for the top two years in which most movies were produced, and I have to sort them chronologically after the years and print only the years.

I am trying this to compute the list and sort it 'the other way around' afterwards but I cannot order by anthing in the last 'order by' statement because in the FROM-statement I dont refer to any tables and instead open the next statement. It says "unknown column topTwo" as well so that I cannot order my results accordingly.

What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT * 
FROM

    (SELECT m.year, COUNT(*)    
     FROM movies as m    
     GROUP BY m.year    
     ORDER BY m.year DESC) AS topTwo    

ORDER BY **topTwo** ASC    
LIMIT 2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
SELECT topTwo.year
FROM (SELECT m.year, COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM movies m    
      GROUP BY m.year    
      ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
      LIMIT 2
     ) topTwo    
ORDER BY year ASC;
```

Notes:

- The `LIMIT` goes in the subquery.
- The `COUNT(*)` is given an alias.
- The `ORDER BY` in the subquery is based on the count.
- The `ORDER BY` in the outer query is based on the year.
- You only seem to want the year, so the outer query only select that column.